# Tensorflow error script

Tags: python

Here is my file:

vim hello.py

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn import linear_model

X = [[0.44, 0.68], [0.99, 0.23]]
vector = [109.85, 155.72]
predict= [0.49, 0.18]

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_ = poly.fit_transform(X)
predict_ = poly.fit_transform(predict)

clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_, vector)
print clf.predict(predict_)
```

I have used this command to run the script:

```
python hello.py
File "hello.py", line 14
print clf.predict(predict_)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please, why i have this error ? This is my first example using tenserflow.

Comment: You're probably using Python3, but your code `print stuff` is Python2-only.

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, `print` needs parentheses to take in arguments:

`print(clf.predict(predict_))`